# Understanding Azure Release Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm very new with Azure DevOps and I need some help to understand how to create a Release Pipeline. The Microsoft Doc is very extensive but I can't find what I'm looking for.

I've created a Build Pipeline with the sample python repository. Then I would like to create a Release Pipeline. I linked my account with my subscription, select the App type, but then I'm asking for App service name.

What is this App service ? How can I create it ?

On their documentation ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/cd/deploy-webdeploy-webapps?view=azure-devops#cd)) they are just saying

`App Service Name: Select the name of the web app from your subscription.`.

No more explanation.

Could someone please give me more information about that ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: just google it? app service is a service offering in azure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- An Azure DevOps release pipeline deploys the artifacts that are the output of a build pipeline to some environment that you define (Test, QA, Production, etc.).
- For web apps the environment will be a "web hosting" (for other apps it could be something different).
- The "web hosting" can be a 3rd party (you would deploy using tasks for FTP, WebDeploy, etc.) or it can be Azure "web hosting" PaaS offering, which is named Azure Web Apps.
- Azure Web Apps require an Azure App Service Plan (which defines its characteristics and pricing): https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/windows/

Note: an Azure App Service can be used not only to host web apps but also to host the back-end (Web APIs) of mobile apps, containers and serverless functions apps. See [App Service overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview) and for high scale and security see [Introduction to the App Service Environments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/intro)

- The template for the Release Pipeline that you have chosen (assuming is the one named "Deploy a Python app to Azure App Service and Azure database for MySQL") is intended to *"Deploy a Python Django, Bottle, or Flask application to an **Azure Web App** and database to Azure Database for MySQL."* Since it's deploying to an Azure Web App, the task asks you for its Azure Subscription and its App Service Plan within that subscription.
- So, if you plan to deploy to an Azure Web App, create a Service Plan in your Azure subscription (you can use the Azure Portal, Azure CLI, etc.). Otherwise remove the task and use a different task to deploy to your 3rd party web hosting.

Comment: Too add: the first point is not entirely correct. You can skip the build step completely and have the release pipeline bound directly to the repository, instead of build pipeline artifacts.

Comment: @Erndob: yes, you are right, in some scenarios. But the original poster had already a build pipeline and he was "very new to Azure DevOps" so I started my explanation from that point.

Answer (score 2):

If you are new to Azure DevOps and want to try out all the cool things, I suggest you to follow [Azure DevOps Labs](https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/) which has a great content to get started from Zero to Advanced.

Comment: Thanks, it looks great i will try it